# RoR Take atrributes from ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm a novice at RoR. Tell me please how to take attributes from ActiveRecord::Relation? For Example I write:

```
@user = User.where(code: 123)
```

next I want to take attribute id

```
id = @user.id
```

but this method is not working. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When use .where **it gives you an [`active record relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) so you can't find id directly on it because it's a relation not a single model object.***

**Fix:**

You can do

```
@user = User.where(code: 123).first
```

OR

You can use [`dynamic finders`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders)

```
@user = User.find_by_code(123)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find single user with `code == 123`, you can use `find_by` method, like this:

```
@user = User.find_by(code: 123)
```

It returns `User` instance, so you can call `id` method on it.

EDIT: If you use Rails prior to 4.x version, you can use dynamic `find_by_code` finder:

```
@user = User.find_by_code(123)
```

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `find_by' for #<Class:0x00000004a69678>):

Comment: @VitaliyProdan - What rails version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `where` clause it returns array. Use it like :

```
@user = User.where(code: 123).first
```

Above is not right way for query. So you can also write your code to find user like :

```
@user = User.find_by_code(123)
```

With above two ways you get single object and you can find any attribute from it. `@user.id` etc

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing `first`, `where` returns an `array` of objects, so you need to use first to get the object out of array

Do this

```
@user = User.where(code: 123).first
id = @user.id
```